# Mixed Poisson process $\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(p(t)\lambda)$

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, poisson-distribution, poisson-process

The capital $C$ of a bank grows proportionally with time:
$$dC = adt$$
Therefore at time $t$, the bank has $at$ units of capital. The bank has to undergo stress
tests, which occur according to a homogeneous Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.
The bank passes a stress test provided that it has at least a suffcient amount of
capital at the moment of the test. The desired minimum amounts of required capitals are random, independent and following a continuous distribution with density

$$f(s)=\frac{4}{\pi(1+s^2)^2}.$$

What is the probability that the bank will pass the stress test ?

**MY TRY**

We can define $N(t)$ to be the number of failed tests up to time $t$. Then,
one knows that $N(t)\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(p(t)\lambda)$ with $p(t)$ the probability to fail:

$$p(t)=\int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{s/a} \frac{4}{\pi(1+s^2)^2} dtds = \frac{2}{\pi a}$$

Then, I know $N(t)\sim\operatorname{Poisson}(\frac{2\lambda}{\pi a})$. But know I do not know why the answer should be $$\exp(-\frac{2\lambda}{\pi a}).$$

I was trying to compute $P(N(t)=0)=\exp(\frac{2\lambda}{\pi a} t)$ and then integrate this for all time $t$. But I do no get the same. Any help?

Comment: No, you don't integrate for all time $t$.  Presumably the bank passes the stress test if there are no failures before time $t=1$.

Comment: Yes, ofc I see that presumably that's what happens. But why?